# How to hide the console in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, console

Since I've started doing serious things with C I need now to know if there's a way to make console (or terminal) not appear when the program starts.

Is there a code line for this?

I'm using SDL.

[image]

EDIT: I use Code::blocks

Comment: I think it's called the console, and you don't want it to go away.  That's where error messages and such will be printed.  Minimize it and get on with your problem.

Comment: This will probably depend on your development environment; which compiler and set up how? Also this therefore might not technically be a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project settings you probably specified that your application is a console application. So the IDE makes sure that a console is opened for you when you launch the program. Change your project settings to fix this.

Edit:
This SO answer is what you're looking for: [How to get ride of console box of a GUI program compile by MinGW + Code::Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003777/how-to-get-ride-of-console-box-of-a-gui-program-compile-by-mingw-codeblock)

Comment: I will try in a moment